# Best practice to draw a chart into a html5 canvas which behaves responsive on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, html5-canvas

I want to draw a complex chart on a canvas element.

The canvas has width and height 100%. The div container of the canvas has a width of 100% and height 640 pixel for mobice device 1. (see below)

Lets assume I draw a rectangle:

```
void rect(x, y, width, height)

context.rect(0,0,100,640);
```

For mobile device 1 I have this context:

width: 480px,
height: 640px

For mobile device 2 I have this context:

width: 1024px,
height: 768px

When I switch now to mobile device 2 my context.height changes from 640px to 768px. The result is that the rectangle with a height of 640px leaves now a gap between it and the top margin of the gap: 768px - 640px = 128px gap.

Question 1)
So the canvas from itself is not able to stretch its content? I do not ask for stretching the canvas itself, thats easy, I just want to stretch the content inside the canvas.

Question 2)
When Question1 answers is "No it can not stretch its content!" then How do I correctly resize its content? Is there a redraw event where I can hook into when the mobile device changes from portrait to landscape view? Or is it up to me to take the height of 640px as 100% and divide the content areas in my canvas into x-% areas and compute for example what is 40% width in pixel related to the 100% (640px) ? This way the content would scale up/down when the height of the mobile device changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: You can "stretch" (==scale) the canvas content using canvas context.scale(scaleX,scaleY).

Note: The content will distort if scaleX is not equal to scaleY.

It works like this:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.scale(768/640, 768/640);
// redraw all your content which will now be 768/640 larger

// and, of course, do this in reverse if the device is reoriented the other way.
```

One problem with mobile reorienting (portrait/landscape) is that multiple resize events will be called as the device reorients.

To prevent this, you might look at jquery mobile's `throttledresize` event which executes just once for each reorientation.  jQuery has the added benefit of simplifying cross-browser issues which do arise when reorienting and resizing.

If you don't want to add a full library to your project, throttledresize works by starting a timer when it notices resizing and executes a callback function when the timer expires.  That way you avoid the multiple resize events that occur with mobile.

Comment: I am using knockoutjs to bind the data to the canvas. Any tip in that direction? :) I have not tested yet wether the canvas code is executed again when I flip my ipad... will do it tomorrow.

Comment: KnockoutJS is a great databinding choice--I'll have more thoughts on that when I have a bit more time.  You will, of course, have to trigger the canvas code inside a resize event--either resize or throttledresize ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to transform the canvas element using CSS "transform"

```
#canvas {
  transform: scale(2,4);
  -ms-transform: scale(2,4); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2,4); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_scale

Comment: This will stretch the canvas but not increase its resolution.

Comment: I thought from Question2 this would also be a proper solution